# NodeJS: How does Writeable-Stream know that there will be no more data?

Tags: node.js, stream

When I'm implementing a writeable stream in node, the only method I have to implement is `_write`. But how do I know that there will be no more data?

The consumer of my stream ends his transmission with `mystream.end(data)`, and he also receives an event `finish` when I'm done with writing. But how do I know about this within my writeable implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Well, a writable will emit a 'finish' event when `writable.end()` is called.
So, add a `finish` event listener, then the handler will be call when writable ends.

```js
class MyWritable extends Stream.Writable {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.on('finish', function() {
      console.log('no more data to be written')
    }
  }
}
```

ref: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_finish

Comment: Writable will emit `finish` only after the last callback will be called, but you know this after you wrote your last chunk.